# Google Sheets - Configuring a CountIF formula with a sample dataset

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Below is the structure of my dataset:

```
Lic#          Avg Payment/Service

1508004193    0.54        
1912006552 .  0.56
1720017593 .  0.56
1770840431 .  0.60
1023001864 .  0.70
1669681458 .  0.72
1699718270 .  0.72
1982858031 .  0.79
1205913621 .  0.87
1174650030 .  0.88
```

How do I write a formula on google sheet to calculate how many Lic# exists with Average Payment/Service between 0.54 and 0.60. The raw data is on **Sheet1** and I am trying to use **Sheet2** to present the aggregated value in a given cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide multiple condition with same range using `COUNTIFS`

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,">=0.54",B:B,"<=0.60")
```

Here is the working snapshot
[image]

Here is the explanation to `COUNTIFS`
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en

Comment: what about ColA. Im trying to count how many fruits in ColA have a price between $1 and $2. Expected result is 5

Comment: Could there be repetition in Col A ?

Comment: No Repeated values. Every fruit occurs only once.

Comment: Then the above formula will work. It counts number of cells in colB whose values are between 1 and 2. Which is same as counting values in colA as it  contains only unique values.

Comment: Your Formula is not working correctly. I tried as below: =COUNTIFS(SHEET1!B1:B1000,">=0.54",Sheet1!B1:B1000,"<=0.60") . The answer should be 4 but it is 3.

Comment: It worked for me. Check my updated answer. I added the snapshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205634/discussion-between-raj-parpani-and-geetanjali).